# combobox autocompletado en C#

Tags: c#

Tengo un combobox que autocompleta con una consulta y quiero que se muestren dos campos por ejemplo IdProyecto y NombreProyecto quiero saber la forma para cuando busque en el combo me aparezca los dos osea el IdProyecto Y NombreProyecto junto este es mi codigo que recorre y busca:

```
DataTable dt = Datos();

        AutoCompleteStringCollection coleccion = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        //recorrer y cargar los items para el autocompletado
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            coleccion.Add(Convert.ToString(row["CNombreProyecto"]));
            coleccion.Add(Convert.ToString(row["CCodigoProyecto"])); 
        }

        return coleccion;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas agregando uno abajo de otro. Si esto no es `wpf` (lo cual mejoraría mucho la solución) lo único que tenes que hacer es concatenar las cadenas a agregar al combo

```
coleccion.Add(Convert.ToString(row["CCodigoProyecto"]) + " - " + Convert.ToString(row["CNombreProyecto"]));
```

Con eso, vas a armar una cadena de tipo

> codigo - nombre

Comment: si me sirvio su respuesta solo que cuando mando los datos del combo a una consulta me manda todo lo del combo como lo concateno a la consulta asi comboBox1.Text le puse comboBox1.valuemember y no me arrojo nada me dijo error de lectura por que no encontro datos.

Comment: Nada de todo lo q estas diciendo aca esta aclarado en tu pregunta. Es mas. En esa funcion solo estas devolviendo algo, que supongo despues agregaras a tu combo. En ese caso, no deberias haberle pasado el datatable directamente? Podes cerrar esta pregunta, y hacer una nueva aclarando todo tu problema completo, pq se ve que tampoco sabes como cargar el combo.

Comment: ok entonces es en otra pregunta..

Comment: Mas que todo, aclara bien el escenario, que tenes y que queres hacer. Si no te van a resolver el problema puntual, como aca y no vas a saber como seguir.

Comment: soy nuevo todavia no se como funciona esto gracias por el dato.

Comment: Entonces por favor mira[ASK]. Bienvenido